# Using mosquitto in a shell script using a pipe

Tags: shell, mosquitto, openwrt

I'm using mosquitto on an openWRT device to receive some data from a server and then send this same data to a local printer to print this data.

I'm using this script to receive the data

```
mosquitto_sub -h "${HOST}" -k 30 -c -p 8883 -t "${TOPIC}" -u "${USERNAME}" -P "${PASSWORD}" --id "${ID}" | /bin/sh /bin/printer_execute "${TOPIC}" "${PRINTER}" "${USERNAME}" "${PASSWORD}"
```

And the printer_execute code:

```
    #!/bin/sh

TOPIC="${1}"
PRINTER="${2}"
USERNAME="${3}"
PASSWORD="${4}"

while read MSG
  do
    echo "input: ${MSG}"
      echo "INPUT MSG: " "${MSG}" >> /root/log
      RES=`curl -m 2 --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction: ''" --header "If-Modified-Since: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" --data "${MSG}" "http://${PRINTER}/cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi?devid=local_printer&timeout=5000"`
      mosquitto_pub -h ${HOST_PLACEHOLDER} -p 8883 -t "${TOPIC}-response" -m "${RES}" -u "${USERNAME}" -P "${PASSWORD}"
    echo "RESULT CURL: " "${RES}" >> /root/log
done
```

This solution works with a relatively low messages per second, but when the volume is too high the printer_execute code stop working. I'm pretty new to shell scripting and I guess the problem could be caused by the pipe and while read pattern or by the while exit condition, but i'm not really sure.

Anyone has some idea or found a similar problem and know how to solve this?

EDIT:
In light of the answers i have tried to do this:

EDIT2: Sorry in the first edit i just added what i modified but the entire script is like that and the scope should be correct for the variables.

```
#!/bin/sh
TOPIC="${1}"
PRINTER="${2}"
USERNAME="${3}"
PASSWORD="${4}"
PrintOne(){
    MSG="${1}"
    RES=$(curl [params])
    mosquitto_pub -h [host] -p 8883 -d -t "${TOPIC}-response" -m "${RES}" -u "${USERNAME}" -P "${PASSWORD}"
    echo "RESULT CURL: " "${RES}" >> /root/log
}

while read msg ; do
        PrintOne "$msg" &
done
```

With the printone and the appersand this take one message and stop working, without the & it's just like it was before.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see what is wrong now. I didn't explicitly show you how to pass all 4 parameters to the function, I was assuming you would do that. Let me improve my answer - hang on a minute.

Comment: Have another look at the bottom of my answer - sorry, I could have been more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a function to handle one message and **calling that in the background** (by appending an ampersand) so that you can respond quickly and in parallel - and that will allow you to take longer to handle each message... for a period. If your messages continually arrive faster than you can handle them, there will inevitably be a backlog.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PrintOne(){
   echo "Received $1"
   curl ...
   mosquitto_pub ...
   echo $RESULT
}

while read msg ; do
    PrintOne "$msg" &
done
```

---

If you want a little example. change the code to this and save it as `go`, and make it executable with `chmod +x go`

```
#!/bin/bash

PrintOne(){
   echo "Received $1"
   sleep 2
   echo "Finished $1"
}

while read msg ; do
    PrintOne "$msg" &
done
```

Now send it 10 lines:

```
seq 10 | ./go
```

Then remove the ampersand, and do exactly the same thing again and you will see the difference.

---

A more complete version of my answer is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

PrintOne(){
   TOPIC="${1}"
   PRINTER="${2}"
   USERNAME="${3}"
   PASSWORD="${4}"
   curl ...
   mosquitto_pub ...
   echo $RESULT
}

while read msg ; do
    PrintOne "${1}" "${2}" "${3}" "${4}" &
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried the go script on my device and that works, but as soon as i do something like
    PrintOne(){
       mosquitto_pub [params]
    }
    while read msg ; do
        PrintOne "$msg" & 
    done
this stop working after the first message; i wonder if there are something with the mosquitto specification i don't know that make this not possible. EDIT: i tried to make the code readable in the comments but the indentation has been removed automatically

Comment: @carmo That's because the comments area is not for code :-) Please click `edit` under your original question and update it with any code you have tried and I will take another look. Thanks.

Comment: edited i still have the doubt that the problem start with mosquitto or curl usage.

Comment: Sorry, check edit2, i wrote only the diff respect the old solution, now i wrote the entirety of the script to avoid miscomunication, i think the scope of the variable should still work right? PS. Those parameters are passed by an external script

Comment: I think you need to pass all 4 parameters to `PrintOne()`

Comment: So, i think i found the problem, i ran the same script on another device (my personal computer) and it works like a charm, so I'm thinking that the embedded device that should print could be having some problem handling many request maybe because of the cpu or ram. I do not know how to debug that but we are making some workaround on the server, now we send one message at a time and wait the response before sending another. It is not very reliable but it works. I'm sorry because i even forget to mention the device capability because i didn't think that could be a factor.